# Совместимость regexp с ltr- и rtl-письменностями

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, локализация, i18n

Нужно «разобрать» по группам фразу. Фраза может быть на любом из 250 языков, в т.ч на rtl-письменности. На английском регулярка такая:

`To use this application [$1|local] or [$2|global] rights is required.`

`^(.*?)\[\$1\|(.*?)\](.*?)\[\$2\|(.*?)\](.*?)$`

Группы:
`To use this application` 
`local`
`or`
`global`
 `rights is required.`

Теперь вбиваем фразу в гугл-переводчик (чтобы не мучать подопытных арабов-тестеров) и не находим регуляркой ни-чё-го. Что делать, господа?

`لاستخدام هذا التطبيق [$ 1 | محلي] أو [$ 2 | عالمي] مطلوب.`

(причём в гугл-переводчике точка в конце rtl, а при копировании оказывается в начале (см. выше))

Comment: Напишите другое регулярное выражение, чудес не бывает. На сайте regex101 работает такое: `/^(.*?)\[1\$\|(.*?)\](.*?)\[2\$\|(.*?)\](.*)$/` ([пример](https://regex101.com/r/aeToLx/1))

Comment: Так как определяются эти группы? Во втором тексте перед `|` есть ещё символ, а в первом нет. При этом не приведён ожидаемый результат для второго текста. Должен ли этот символ попасть в какую-то группу или нет? В какую?

Comment: @dIm0n простите, о каком символе вы говорите? В упор не вижу. Пробел? Это почему то при вставке арабского текста в поле для редактирования они добавляются. Я не знаю, почему. На всякий случай сделал \s?

Comment: Во втором тексте на арабском перед самым первым `|`

Comment: Пробелов там быть не должно. Если бы вы решили "мучать подопытных арабов-тестеров", они бы вам эти пробелы не вставили, это баг-фича Google Translate, они просто вставляют пробелы при токенизации переводимого текста.

Answer (score 0):

На первый взгляд у вас всё правильно, просто мешают пробелы, которые появились после автоматического перевода. Ввёл ваше регулярное выражение и текст на упомянутом выше https://regex101.com/, оно не сработало, но, после того, как убрал четыре пробела, которые не соответствовали вашему регулярному выражению (между цифрой, символом «$» и следующим за ним символом «|»), регулярное выражение сработало. Единственное, что последнее слово не было подсвечено, но это похоже на недоработку самого сайта, потому что в правой части страницы показано содержимое, подошедшее под выражения в скобках, и там вроде бы все ожидаемые символы. И ещё стоит удалить пару пробелов после «|» (чтобы было как в английском). Вот пример: https://regex101.com/r/3nT6Ql/1/